# How do I add an extra 0 for the cent amount in dollars in php?

Tags: php, string, decimal

```
$dollar_amount_purchased = $dollar_amount_purchased + "0";
```

I tried the above code but it's not working. How am I supposed to do this in php?

Comment: `+` does not concatenate strings in PHP, it only adds numbers. `.` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: Somebody's been coding too much javaascriiiipt ;)

Comment: oops, yes I meant . instead of +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Note that this function is now deprecated and using it is discouraged against.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Note that this function is now deprecated and using it is discouraged against.

Answer (score -1):

Format numbers for display with `number_format`. The first parameter is how many decimal places you want to show. If you specify 2 and the number does not have a tenths or hundredths place, it'll get padded with 0s automatically.

```
echo '$' . number_format($dollar_amount_purchased, 2, '.', ',');
```